# prefill Formstack form field with timestamp?

Tags: javascript, formstack

Apologies for a newbie question. I'm not a developer.

When the form loads, I'd like to display the epoch timestamp as a number in a read-only field.
(I want a unique ID for each submission and cannot use the Submission ID for our needs.)

We have very basic Formstack Forms and there's no option in settings to load JavaScript so I am using the Embed Code field in the form itself. Appreciate someone getting me on the right path.

The field is labeled "ID".  When I inspect the form in preview, that field is 159978255.

I was trying this JavaScript built from previous examples on this forum, but the field loads empty.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     //Do something before the form loads
    function FF_OnBeforeRender(){
      var timeStamp = +new Date;
      document.getElementById('159978255').value = timeStamp ;
    };
    </script>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You're never calling your function - it's only *defined*, and never used. Try adding `FF_OnBeforeRender()` above `</script>` .

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but my belief was this piece of code would place the timestamp into the field before the form loaded (I guess like a prefill). 

I want to hard code the current timestamp as the value of this field when the form loads.  Preferably in a way that is easy for me (or others) to understand quickly.

Comment: Apologies for missing the formstack tag. I've checked [the documentation](https://help.formstack.com/s/article/Javascript-API) for this function, and I've noticed this: "The function should either return true if processing should continue or false otherwise". Try adding `return true;` as the last line in your function. Also, if you're not sure if the function is called - add  `alert("It's running");` as the first thing before `var timeStamp = ...` . The last thing I'd think would be useful - inside the function, check if your `#159978255` exists.

Comment: The alert appears when it reaches the embed code field but the ID field stays blank.  I have tried ID'ing the field as "ID", "#ID", "159978255" and "#159978255".  I have tried using number field and a textbox. 

This is where the script stands now...
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTimestamp() { 
    alert("It's running"); // debugging
 var timeStamp = +new Date;     
// collect the epoch timestamp
 document.getElementById('159978255').value = timeStamp; 
// prefill the ID field with epoch timestamp
return true;
 } 
addTimestamp()
</script>

Comment: Perhaps your element is not there once the document is loaded. Can you try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ey6bajzk/ ? The idea is to check if the element shows up at a certain point. You would be monitoring the console for the exact moment it does, and you could change its value once it shows up.